# R Help: Daily time series on business days

Tags: time-series, r

I have a daily time series in a csv file. With the below command I read the data in a data.frame

```
test <- read.csv("xxxx.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=",")
```

I want then to convert it in a time series object. Notice that the dates start at  02/01/2009 (d/m/Y) and end at 15/09/2016 (d/m/Y). I list below the number of observations per year:
2009 250 obs.
2010 250 obs.
2011 248 obs.
2012 249 obs.
2013 250 obs.
2014 250 obs.
2015 250 obs.
2016 179 obs. up to 15/09/2016

I now that the ts method needs start and end dates and a frequency. For monthly data it is staraightforward to use fr = 12. What about my case? How may I create a time series object for daily data on working days?

I use this approach:

```
test.ts <- ts(test$Value, start = c(2009, 2), end = c(2016, 179), frequency = 250)
```

Comment: I use zoo library. First I parse the date column from a csv file and convert it to Date object with as.Date function and store it in a variable named working.days. Then I create the zoo object with zoo(x=test$Value, order.by=working.days), and store in a variable named test.ts. Methods as plot are avaliable. Is something that I can do with ts object and cannot do with a zoo object?